# How can copy 4 character from begining of string to end of string?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

For example:

```
var
s:string;
begin
s:='Hello1234567';

end;
end.
```

How can I copy from string 4 byte 4 byte..Example showmessage('hell') and showmessage('o123')
and showmessage('4567')?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Copy()` function for that:

```
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'Hello1234567';
  ShowMessage(Copy(s, 1, 4));
  ShowMessage(Copy(s, 5, 4));
  ShowMessage(Copy(s, 9, 4));
end;
```